# What is the OpenStates API rate limit?

Tags: api

I have a project where I need to use the OpenStates API to retrieve information. The code is written and works, I just need to know what the rate limiting is before I turn it on.

I have read through the [documentation](https://docs.openstates.org/en/latest/api/index.html) and did not find it, does anyone know what the OpenState API rate limits are?

Answer (score 1):

This pull request seems to suggest that a [sleep rate of 1 was reduced to 0.5](https://github.com/openstates/pyopenstates/issues/8)

[The source code](https://github.com/openstates/pyopenstates/commit/01b19cfdfc37b6b97eb7b958c2fa9fb98fef1229) for the request is here.

Comment: Is there a total requests per day limit as well?

Comment: That is all that I could find.